# Loki 0.4.0 touchscreen support

Tags: release-loki, input, touchscreen, lenovo

How do I enable touchscreen support on my Lenovo Yoga 3? The screen rotation works perfectly, but touch/scrolling/multitouch do not.

Comment: What a shame, the touch panel on the Dell XPS 9360 has worked out of the box. Did you get this working in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS DOES support touch. I have Dell XPS 15 with a touch screen and am running Loki without any special touch modifications. It all works as you would expect (including being annoying when someone touches your screen). I can click, drag, move and do so in combination with modifier keys. I'll be clicking on the "Post Your Answer" by touching the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS does not yet support touch but soon they will we have plans

Comment: but they have added this in just not all pcs work sorry

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? How have you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Elementary DOES support Touch, because I'm using it on my Dell Venue Pro with touch support. It doesn't work well in every scenario, but you can use touch.

However, you may be missing some drivers for touch. Lenovo may need different module.

My Dell Venue uses two touch sensors provided by Wacom, so they are recognized properly.